# $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $rank A=n-1$, then $Ax=0, A'x=0$ has a base $\alpha,\beta$ respectively. Show $\alpha\beta'$ is a polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> $A$  is a $n\times n$ matrix, $rank A=n-1$, then $Ax=0, A'x=0$ has a base $\alpha,\beta$ respectively. [That is, the linear equation $Ax=0$ a solution $\alpha\neq 0$; $A'x=0$ has a solution $\beta\neq 0$] Show $\alpha\beta'$ is a polynomial of $A$.

Here, $A'$ is the transpose of $A$.

I know only that if $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvector, then $BA=AB$ implies $B$ is a polynomial of $A$.

What about this problem. Let $B=\alpha\beta'$, then $AB=0=BA$. Would this help?

Comment: what do you mean by $\alpha$ is a base?

Comment: Have you tried working with the adjugate and minimal polynomial of $A$?

Comment: @user8675309 OK, I got it.